# Android rawQuery call crashing app

Tags: android, sqlite

I 'm making this call:

```
sql=select * from Lists where Name = test
Cursor cr = GetUserDb().GetSQLiteDb().rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Name is the primary key

Its right at the rawQuery() call , because  GetUserDb() & GetSQLiteDb() are not null.

The logcat says:

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: test: , while compiling: select * from Lists where Name = test. That doesn't make sense to me because test is not a column name its data in the Name Column.

Whats causing it to crash?

-Mike

Comment: Try putting 'test' in single quotes, i.e. make it a string literal.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with sqlite syntax, but my best guess is that you need "test" to be in some form of quotes, or however strings are delimited in sqlite queries

Comment: Nope work didn't as expected. I tried single and double quotes. Just not sure why it thinks 'test' is a column?? hmmmmm....

Comment: Ok wait it did work , I must not have done it right the first time. This worked:                                                                           final String s = "select * from Lists where Name = 'test'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: final String s = "select * from Lists where Name = 'test'";